# Strategy for simple yet effective UDP server for gaming (and other tasks)

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, client-side

i'm trying to implment my idea of simple yet pretty effective multithreaded server working on UDP. Main goal is for gaming(-like) applications, but it would be good if it could be used in other purposes too.

I want to use this API/technologies etc

1. STD::Thread for multithreading, since it is part of C++ standard, it should be future-proof and as far as i seen it it's both simple and works well with C++.
2. BSDSock (Linux) & WinSock2 (Windows). I would create one **abstract class** called Socket and for each platform (Linux - BSD, Windows - WinSock) create derived class implementing native API. Then i would use API provided by base class Socket, not native/platform API. That would allow me to use one code for whole server/client module and if i want to change platform i'd have to just switch class type of socket and thats it.

As for **strategy** of server-client comunication i thought of something like this:
Each programm has two sockets - one that listens on specified port and one that is used to send data to server/other clients. Both sockets run on different threads so that i can both read and send data at the same time (sort of), that way waiting for data won't ruin my performance. There will be one main server, and other clients will connect directly to that server. Clients will send only their data and recieve data directly from server.

Now i have some **question**:

1. Is it wise to use STD::Thread? I heard it's good on Linux, but not that good on Windows. Would PThreads would be much better?
2. Any other interesting ideas about making one code for many platforms (mainly Linux&Windows)? Or mine is good enough?
3. Any other ideas or some tips about strategy for how server/client would work? I wrote some simple network apps, but it didn't need that good strategy, so i'm not sure if it's best from simple ideas.
4. How often should i send data from client to server (and from server to client)? I dont want to flood the network and to make server load 100%?

Also: it should work nice with 2-4 players at the same time, i don't plan to use it with more at the moment.

Comment: To get something OS independent you should take a look at [`boost::asio`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) or [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/). Also please try to ask one question at a time, as it is yours is pretty broad!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - yes, i realise using lib like boost would be easier and whole lot better, but i want to learn something for myself and writing something like that would give me some inside knowledge on topic and some experience.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, from multi-threading purposes Linux + Pthread would be a nice combination. A vast number of mission critical systems are running on that combination. However, when we come to std::thread, having platform dependent nature is a nice to have feature. Certainly, if some bad smells are in windows dialect, MS would correct them future. BUT, if I were you, I will certainly select Linux + std::thread combination. Selection of Linux over Windows is a different topic and no need to comment here (with respect to server development perspective). std::thread provides you a nice set of feature,yet having the power of pthreads.

Regarding UDP, you have both pros and cons. But, I'd say if you are going to open your sever for public, you have to think about network firewalls as well. If you can address the inherent transport layer issues of UDP (packet re-ordering, lost packet recovery), a UDP server is light weighted in most of the cases.

It depends on your game to decide how often you need to send messages. I can't comment it.

Moreover, pay your attention to extra security on your data communication more seriously. Sooner or later your sever will be hacked. It is just a matter of fact of TIME.

Comment: 1. I'm trying to make something cross-platforms (both on Linux and windows) and i want to use one lib/API for that. So you say staying with STD::thread for both linux and windows would be better, right?

2. UDP stays, since it will be real-time multiplayer game, so i need speed. Some data loss will be acceptable.

3. As for security i plan it to be small game that maybe not too many ppl will play, so for now it's not big concern. I dont think it will be that popular ;) Though good point for future concerns.

Comment: I'm saying. Normally threading with windows sucks. At least from server applications' perspective. Regardless of windows threads or std::thread, try to ignore windows for your sever if possible. If it is std::thread in windows it should ultimately access windows OS level features. There are lots of practical  failure examples of usage of windows in server applications.

Comment: @SargiEran `std::thread` implementation in VS c++ 2013 should be OK.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's absolutely nice to hear.